# Liquibase Hibernate inconsistency

Tags: spring, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

After upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4.2 and Hibernate 5, I can't get schema generation through Liquibase Hibernate to work correctly anymore. I switched to `liquibase-hibernate5` 3.6 and sorted out the naming strategy, but I'm still stuck on two issues:

- `AttributeConverter` marked with `autoapply` is not applied. I could work around that by explicitly applying it, but I'm still mentioning it as it might provide a hint for the next issue.
- A `byte[]` is generated as a `BLOB` while Hibernate expects it to be a `VARBINARY` at runtime.

This is how I invoke Liquibase:

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=src/main/liquibase/base/entity.yml --url=hibernate:spring:nu.yona.server?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy generateChangeLog
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase has a bug with Blob and PostgreSQL I opened a pull request to resolve it
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/605